# url friendly AdsManager

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla3.0

I have problem with url friendly AdsManager.
For details on the url I get all ads and I want to leave alone title details or details.

Eg.: `example.com/todos-anuncios/-/234-vendo...ra-xbox-360-en-.html`

want out

```
example.com/vendo-fifa14-para-xbox-360-en-.html
```

As I can solucionarl?
It is very important because I utiilzo module isotope which is why I get this module in detail and not have to leave. Can anybody help me?

I researched the file router.php and .htaccess router.php seems construie the url from this part

```
/234-vendo-fifa14-para-xbox-360-en-.html
```

in full url

```
example.com/todos-anuncios/-/234-vendo...ra-xbox-360-en-.html
```

is not responsible for example.com/todos-anuncios/ this part

Even if I agree to this ad pulsano link on the map, but from home.
I get url

```
example.com/component/adsmanager/-/234...ra-xbox-360-en-.html
```

but if I go all ads the url is another

```
example.com/todos-anuncios/-/234-vendo...ra-xbox-360-en-.html
```

although url are different, showing me exactly the same content.

It's very complicated issue and I can not do to fix it.

I tried to install component sh404 but does not install me, shows me error:

```
JInstaller:: Install: Can not find XML setup file
```

Some ideas how I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I researched the file `router.php`
and `.htaccess`
`router.php` seems construie the url from

this part

```
/234-vendo-fifa14-para-xbox-360-en-.html
```

in full url

```
alanuncio.com/todos-anuncios/-/234-vendo...ra-xbox-360-en-.htm
```

is not responsible for alanuncio.com/todos-anuncios/ this part

Even if I agree to this ad pulsano link on the map, but from home.
I get url

```
alanuncio.com/component/adsmanager/-/234...ra-xbox-360-en-.html
```

but if I go all ads
the url is another

```
alanuncio.com/todos-anuncios/-/234-vendo...ra-xbox-360-en-.html
```

although url are different, showing me exactly the same content.

It's very complicated issue and I can not do to fix it.

I tried to install component
  sh404
but does not install me, shows me error:

JInstaller:: Install: Can not find XML setup file

Some ideas how I fix it?